# Writing an environment to take in comma separated values passed within a single argument {...}?

Tags: tables, spacing

I am relatively new to Latex and am having a hard time figuring out how to pass multiple comma separated values to a single `{}` argument. For the problem at hand,
I need to pass either 3 or 4 single characters like `{A,B,C}` or `{A,B,C,D}`. I am attempting to define a new environment on top of the the `karnaugh-map` environment provided by the `karnaugh-map` package. Below is the main code I am interested in:

```
% This does not take in any argument as of yet 
\newenvironment{kmap}{
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][4][1][$CD$][$AB$]% <-- these environment options are what I want to set via the argument
}%
{\end{karnaugh-map}
\vspace{-2em}}
```

There are only two use cases I am interested in :

```
\begin{kmap}{w,x,y,z} % 4 args passed
% stuff
\end{kmap}
```

would expand to

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][4][1][$yz$][$wx$]
% stuff
\end{karnaugh-map}
```

and

```
\begin{kmap}{P,Q,R} % 3 args passed
% stuff
\end{kmap}
```

would expand to

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$QR$][$P$]
% stuff
\end{karnaugh-map}
```

This might look unnecessary but I plan to add a lot of other stuff within the environment/command if I can get this done. Any help is greatly appreciated. If this could be more easily achieved via a command instead of an environment that would be great too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` with `\SplitArgument`:

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{kmap}{>{\SplitArgument{3}{,}}m}
  {%
    \kmap@#1%
  }
  {%
    \end{karnaugh-map}
  }
\newcommand\kmap@[4]
  {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}
      {\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$#2#3$][$#1$]}% only 3 values were given
      {\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][4][1][$#3#4$][$#1#2$]}% 4 values were given
  }
\makeatother
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. thanks.